# Conky in C/C++ language

Tags: linux, linux-mint, conky

I want to change image of my desktop in mint :)
I wan to add sth like conky to desktop but I don't know LUA language :(
Is it possible to write it in C/C++ language? (for example I want to connect with forecast server to download some png with my weather and so on:)

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that conky supports C/C++. But you can find many sample conky/lua scripts on google. It's not hard to find something close to what your looking for in appearance and in features, and simply modify the conky and lua scripts manually through trial and error. Its really quite easy to decipher. You can also check the conky man page for info: 
http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

Lua is extremely easy to learn, definitely a lot easier compared to C/C++.  I suggest you check out the book [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/) and learn the basics.  If you really want to use C, you can always call C functions from Lua and do the real work there.  It is explained in the book aswell ;-)